# Nodejs native addon weird segmentation fault

Tags: c++, node.js, segmentation-fault, nan, v8

I am developing a node addon and I am facing some weird issues with segmentation faults. In the MyClass.cc I declared a struct and a NAN_METHOD as follows:

```
struct ComputeContext {
    int test = 1;
};

NAN_METHOD(MyClass::Foo) {
    ComputeContext ctx;
    info.GetReturnValue().Set(Nan::New(true));
}
```

The weird things is, when I call this method from JavaScript, the program exits and with a segmentation fault. However, if I dont initialize test, e.g. `int test;`, it does not crash or report a segfault. To detect segmentation faults I am using the segfault-handler package.

Maybe someone has a clue about what is going on here? As a sidenote, MyClass::Foo is a static method, not sure if that makes a difference.

Comment: Have you tried debugging it and checking which line is causing the crash?

Comment: Unfortunately, I haven't set up the environment for debugging. I think that would require to build v8, libuv and node from source. But anyways, the segfault-handler says it crashes at 'info.GetReturnValue().Set(Nan::New(true));'. Indeed the behaviour is very strange.

Comment: It would only require to build your extension with debug symbols and to run it under debugger.

Comment: Well I can build a debug version of my addon, but what tool do you recommend for debugging? I am using msvc, in order to run the debugger in Visual Studio wouldn't it require me to have the static libs of v8, nodejs, libuv or am I confusing something here?

Comment: If you can build it with Visual Studio then you should be able to debug it with Visual Studio just fine. Building addon requires only import lib of node.js (which will include v8 libuv and whatever else nodejs is using) and you already have it if you mange to build it.

Comment: No the thing is I am building it with node-gyp, which complies it with msvc not with Visual Studio, but I will probably just research how to debug native node modules, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, turned out I had another struct called ComputeContext defined in a different .cc file. MSVC didn't throw any error and linked both files. This caused the segmentation faults when creating instances of the struct.